# How to create a polygon in maya API C++

Tags: c++, api, plugins, graphics, maya

Getting into maya C++ API plugin development. I just want to create a plugin that generates a cube of unit size 1 when the plugin in run as a sort of hello world plugin.

How do I do this? There seems to be a serious dearth of tutorials on how to do simple things. I've looked at the Maya API C++ examples, but there's no description for what the examples do that I can see.

Answer (score 3):

I've created this example using the Python API 2.0 so you can execute it inside the script editor and play with it, before using the C++ API that doesn't really gives you the same flexibility.

```python
import maya.cmds as mc

import maya.api.OpenMaya as OpenMaya


mesh = OpenMaya.MFnMesh()

# Simple unitCube coordinates
vertices = []
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(1, 1, 1))       # 0
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(1, -1, 1))      # 1
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(1, -1, -1))     # 2
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(1, 1, -1))      # 3
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(-1, -1, 1))     # 4
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(-1, 1, 1))      # 5
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(-1, 1, -1))     # 6
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(-1, -1, -1))    # 7

# Number of vertices per polygon
polygonCounts = []
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)

# How each group of N vertices per polygon is connected.
#
# Because for each vertex I have specified the list index number, I can use the
# same number to uniquely identify each face of the polygon to actually build
# the connection between each vertex.
polygonConnects = []

# First polygon
polygonConnects.append(0)
polygonConnects.append(1)
polygonConnects.append(2)
polygonConnects.append(3)

# Second polygon
polygonConnects.append(0)
polygonConnects.append(5)
polygonConnects.append(4)
polygonConnects.append(1)

# Third polygon
polygonConnects.append(5)
polygonConnects.append(6)
polygonConnects.append(7)
polygonConnects.append(4)

# Fourth polygon
polygonConnects.append(6)
polygonConnects.append(3)
polygonConnects.append(2)
polygonConnects.append(7)

# Fifth polygon
polygonConnects.append(0)
polygonConnects.append(3)
polygonConnects.append(6)
polygonConnects.append(5)

# Sixth polygon
polygonConnects.append(1)
polygonConnects.append(4)
polygonConnects.append(7)
polygonConnects.append(2)

mesh.create(vertices, polygonCounts, polygonConnects)
```

In this example:

**MFnMesh** is the API class that handles the mesh and the operation on them.

You can find a more complete documentation here:

- [MFnMesh - Python API 2.0](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__py_ref_class_open_maya_1_1_m_fn_mesh_html)
- [MFnMesh - C++ API](http://help.autodesk.com/view/MAYAUL/2017/ENU/?guid=__cpp_ref_class_m_fn_mesh_html)

Basically, to generate your own mesh you need 3 things:

1. An array of points (specifically MPoints)
2. An array of vertex count per faces
3. An array of vertex id per faces.

So, in a cube we will have:

1. The first array with 8 elements (because a cube has 8 vertices - I'm not taking into account eventual subdivisions)
2. The second array with 6 elements (because a cube has 6 faces)
3. The third array with `6 * 4` elements because for each face we have 4 vertices.

The first array is pretty simple and self explanatory in the unit cube situation:

```python
vertices = []
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(1, 1, 1))       # 0
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(1, -1, 1))      # 1
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(1, -1, -1))     # 2
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(1, 1, -1))      # 3
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(-1, -1, 1))     # 4
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(-1, 1, 1))      # 5
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(-1, 1, -1))     # 6
vertices.append(OpenMaya.MPoint(-1, -1, -1))    # 7
```

As you can see I have 8 vertices, each one with the specific coordinate relative to the origin.

The second array is simple as well.

```python
polygonCounts = []
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
polygonCounts.append(4)
```

Here I've defined that my cube will have, for each face, 4 vertices (so is composed by quads).

Finally the last array.

With this one you will describe not only witch vertex needs to be used to draw each 4-sided face, but also helps you to define the normal orientation of each face, based on the order of insertion of the vertex ids.

```python
polygonConnects = []

# First polygon
polygonConnects.append(0)
polygonConnects.append(1)
polygonConnects.append(2)
polygonConnects.append(3)

# Second polygon
polygonConnects.append(0)
polygonConnects.append(5)
polygonConnects.append(4)
polygonConnects.append(1)

# Third polygon
polygonConnects.append(5)
polygonConnects.append(6)
polygonConnects.append(7)
polygonConnects.append(4)

# Fourth polygon
polygonConnects.append(6)
polygonConnects.append(3)
polygonConnects.append(2)
polygonConnects.append(7)

# Fifth polygon
polygonConnects.append(0)
polygonConnects.append(3)
polygonConnects.append(6)
polygonConnects.append(5)

# Sixth polygon
polygonConnects.append(1)
polygonConnects.append(4)
polygonConnects.append(7)
polygonConnects.append(2)
```

So, the first face is build with the vertices: `[0, 1, 2, 3]` and because of their position, in space, this order also defines that the normal of this face points to `[1, 0, 0]`.

The same for all the other faces.

The last line:

```python
mesh.create(vertices, polygonCounts, polygonConnects)
```

Simply tells the `MFnMesh` object to create a new mesh with the given properties.

---

In this example I haven't built the UVs for this unit cube to avoid adding complexity to this example.

So if you open the UV editor with the cube selected, no UV will shows up.

This is not a big deal, because you can create the UVs and unwrap the polygon the way you like, but if you want to create even the UVs the process is pretty much the same, except that you also need to call the method `assignUV` to actually apply the UV to the polygon.

---

**WARNING**

This process only creates the mesh, and anything else.

This means that when you execute this code the mesh in the viewport will be green, this means that no shader is assigned to the mesh.

---

A snippet with the full example
https://gist.github.com/andrearastelli/fb297e6cac8cb745e90c273e7ff53a1d